# Dynamic filtering, sorting and paging on generic list with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, asp.net-mvc-4, generic-programming

I am using jQuery datatable (http://www.datatables.net) in my MVC4 app and as you may know this table allows server side processing. I am going to use the table in multiple views tied to multiple controllers so I'd like to implement a generic way to filer, sort and page data without the need to write a method for each controller. If I were to do that, they would all look the same but they would target a different entity from the database and be doing textual filtering and sorting on different columns. Here what I have to do today:

```
    public virtual ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        var myProducts = _productRepository.Products;
        IEnumerable<Product> filteredProducts = myProducts;

        // Filtering
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
        {
            var searchTermLower = param.sSearch.Trim().ToLower();
            filteredProducts = filteredProducts
                     .Where(c => c.Title.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 ||
                      c.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName.ToLower().Contains(searchTermLower)
                                 ||
                      c.Category.CategoryTitle.ToLower().Contains(searchTermLower)
                                 ||
                      c.Size.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchTermLower)
                                 ||
                      c.Price.ToString("C").Contains(searchTermLower));
        }

        // Sorting
        var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
        var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"];
        if (sortColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            filteredProducts = sortDirection == "asc" ? filteredProducts.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate) : filteredProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);
        }
        else if (sortColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            filteredProducts = sortDirection == "asc" ? filteredProducts.OrderBy(x => x.Title) : filteredProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title);
        }
        else if (sortColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            filteredProducts = sortDirection == "asc" ? filteredProducts.OrderBy(x => x.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName) : filteredProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName);
        }
        else if (sortColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            filteredProducts = sortDirection == "asc" ? filteredProducts.OrderBy(x => x.Size.Title) : filteredProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Size.Title);
        }
        else if (sortColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            filteredProducts = sortDirection == "asc" ? filteredProducts.OrderBy(x => x.Category.CategoryTitle) : filteredProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Category.CategoryTitle);
        }
        else if (sortColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            filteredProducts = sortDirection == "asc" ? filteredProducts.OrderBy(x => x.Price) : filteredProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price);
        }

        // Paging
        var displayedProducts = filteredProducts.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedProducts
                     select new[] { c.ProductId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), c.CreatedDate.ToString("G"), c.Title, c.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName, c.Size.Title, c.Category.CategoryTitle, c.Price.ToString("C") };
        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = myProducts.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredProducts.Count(),
            aaData = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I tried several things to make this generic none of which worked completely - some because of the fact that I filter on all columns and others for other reasons. I am hoping there is a better way to do this so I can just pass columns or functions that select columns instead and have it work.

Comment: You are doing this on an IEnumerable from your repository, it would be better within the repository.  When I do this type of thing, I use dapper http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ for large tables and just client side filterting for smaller tables as EF queries can get large and complex on this type of thing.

Comment: I am actually passing a repository (DdContext) list as IEnumerable so that any controller can use it.

Comment: "passing a DdContext list as IEnumerable" yes, and for large datasets this is an issue.
Because the compiler will choose IEnumerable.OrderBy() (as opposed to IQueryable.OrderBy()) and therefore the sorting will happen in memory.
For large Datasets I'd advise to let the DB do this.

Comment: Why don't you just use OData?

Comment: This is three questions in one. For all separate parts solutions can (now) be found on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. The question itself should be closed as lacking focus.

Answer (score 1):

Having just recently dealt with this issue I can tell you that you want to implement dynamic linq in your project.
Dynamic linq allows you to write queries such as

results.OrderBy( "id desc" )

and

results.Where( "Name.Contains( 'foo' )" )

Hope these help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx
http://codefucius.blogspot.com/2012/11/implementing-jqgrid-search.html

Note - I used jqGrid, but the idea remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SortingAndPagingHelper extension method

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension method for sorting and filtering
/// </summary>
public static class SortingAndPagingHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> SortingAndPaging<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, SortingAndPagingInfo sortingModal)
    {
        // Gets the coloumn name that sorting to be done on
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = source.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperty(sortingModal.SortColumnName);

        // sorts by ascending if sort criteria is Ascending otherwise sorts descending
        return sortingModal.SortOrder == "Ascending" ? source.OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).Skip(sortingModal.PageSelected * sortingModal.PageSize).Take(sortingModal.PageSize)
                           : source.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).Skip(sortingModal.PageSelected * sortingModal.PageSize).Take(sortingModal.PageSize);
    }
}
```